# Creating textfields after hitting a button (Eclipse/Android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button

I am trying to learn android development in Eclipse and I am stuck. I created a button with using this.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="bla"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="15dp"
     android:id="@+id/bla"
    />
```

And my listener is the following.

```
button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bla);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                    }
                });
```

What I want is the following. When I click my button I want 3 different textfields to be seen. After I enter some values to that textfields, I want to get back to the initial screen which contains button1. How can I do that? Also with which method I can store the values that are written to this textfields?

Edit:All answers were helpful and I upvoted them but I accepted Diego's answer because of the clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `EditText` appear after you click a `Button` you can include all of them in the same XML layout file, set the `EditText` to **INVISIBLE** (`android:visibility="invisible"`) and change it to **VISIBLE** in the OnClick listener.

Answer (score 2):

To create EditText call this on OnButton Click

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout2);
EditText tv;
List<EditText> allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    tv = new EditText(this);
    tv.setText("Dynamic TextView" + i);
    tv.setId(i + 5);
    ll.addView(tv);
}
```

And get inserted values from EditText check this

```
String[] strings = new String[allEds.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < allEds.size(); i++) {
    strings[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Initially create 3 edit text's in your xml file and place them as invisible like android:visibility="invisible" for each and every edit text,
now in our java file when button is clicked visible them. like buttonid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);